# Why does this Regex not work Properly?

Tags: regex

i have the Following Regex:

```
 ^\d{1,5}.*[^0-9][0-9]{5}$
```

and the following text: **123 King Drive 12 OH 12345**

i want to match the strings which start with a 1 to 5-digit number and end with a 5-digit number and have no other numbers between them. But i always get the whole text as a match although it should skip because of the **12** which is between **123** and **12345**.

Why is this happening? shouldn't `[^0-9]` do the trick?

Comment: Why do you have .* if you don't want everything ?

Comment: @dystroy i added .* because there is definitely some characters between a house number (123) and ZIP

Comment: Reading your regex aloud, it says "1-5 digits, followed by *any number of any character*, followed by *1 non-digit character*, followed by 5 digits."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex:

```
^\d{1,5}.*[^0-9][0-9]{5}$
```

And example text:

```
123 King Drive 12 OH 12345
```

--

^\d{1,5} is matching "123"

.* is matching " King Drive 12 OH"

[^0-9] is matching " "

[0-9]{5}$ is matching "12345"

As others have also suggested, something like this would avoid this issue, as you are explicitly saying (unlike by using ".*") not to match any non-digits in the middle of the string:

```
^\d{1,5}\D+\d{5}$
```

Comment: Thanks, what should i add to my Regex if I also wanted to check for Keyword 'Drive' as well?

Comment: ^\d{1,5}\D+[dD]rive\D+\d{5}$ --- I've used [dD] in case you want to include the uncapitalised word too.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the description you make of your requirement, you seem to want this :

```
^\d{1,5}[^0-9]*[0-9]{5}$
```

The `.*` part was matching anything, so not excluding the digits.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `.*` which matches *anything*, what about

```
^\d{1,5}[^0-9]+[0-9]{5}$
```

or more compactly

```
^\d{1,5}\D+\d{5}$
```

`\D` matches any non-digit. You can use `\D*` if you want to allow strings with nothing between the starting and ending digits.

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
^\d{1,5}\D*\d{5}$
```

This reads as "1-5 digits, followed by any number of non-digit characters, followed by 5 digits." If you want at least 1 non-digit character, use `\D+`.

Your previous regex would match because `' King Drive 12 OH'` would match `.*` and `' '` would match the single character `[^0-9]`.